# How long does it take for calcium carbonate to calcium oxide if constant heat of 850 degree Celsius is given?

Tags: decomposition

I am using a muffle furnace and the temperature is set for 850 degree Celsius .
I have placed 100g of Calcium carbonate ( in the form of seas shells) in the furnace .

How long will it take to completely convert calcium carbonate into calcium oxide ?

Comment: Check periodically the mass and evaluate the time series. It cannot be determined from simple principles and it depends on many variables. Even if the estimation is based on empirical knowledge like in chem. engineering, different scenarios can lead to different results.

Comment: Be aware that sea shells are natural composite material, containing organic components protecting them against fragility. there is possibility the result could be blackened by not oxidized carbon or organic origin.

Comment: At this temperature it is likely to take forever, since You asked for complete decomposition. However, partial decomposition into impure product strongly depends on the seashell thickness and other substances present in the biological composite.

Answer (score 1):

Since the calcination is a heterogenous process, the reaction rate depends on the surface area of the shell material exposed to the heat. Therefore you have to consider not only the size of calcium carbonate crystals, but also their macroscopic arrangement, size of the reactor etc. Secondly, the reaction is reversible. The faster $\ce{CO2}$ leaves the system the better (for example, a nitrogen flow might help).

Because of these considerations - as Poutnik has already mentioned in his commentary - it would be hard to tell when your reaction would be complete.

I would say that the shells are unlikely to decompose within minutes - rather, you should count on several hours. If it is safe, leave your setup overnight. Otherwise, run it from morning till evening.

When the decomposition is complete the sea shells will be cracked into greyish mat pieces (not glossy anymore). You could of course test the action of an acid onto your product (to be sure that the starting carbonate has gone).

Lastly, you could consider the calcination of the chicken egg shell. As a rule, it is thinner than the sea shells and should decompose faster.